# Setting the global NPM folder

Tags: node.js, windows-7, installation, npm, gulp

So ultimately, I am trying to install gulp by following this tutorial http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp, and I was having a lot of problems initially. I kept getting the error that "gulp is not recognized as an internal or external command", which is confusing to me because I found that by running npm ls that gulp had been installed properly. The command wasn't being recognized even after restarting command prompt. I found an article online http://blog.webbb.be/command-not-found-node-npm/ that I may have installed gulp in my local folder other than the global node_module folder. However, when I tried to reset the npm folder with npm config set prefix usr/local/, I received errors. If anyone can walk me through getting the global NPM folder set up and getting the gulp command to work properly, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `npm ls -g` show anything? Did you install gulp globally? -> `npm install -g gulp`

Comment: I ran that line (npm install -g gulp) before and it seemed to work fine, but now running npm ls -g comes up empty, and running npm install -g gulp gives me a string of errors:

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\node_modules'
npm ERR! ( [Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\node_modules']
npm ERR! errno: 50
...

you should not have to install gulp globally every time correct? I'm wondering why, all of a sudden, it does not appear to be installed.

Comment: I think your node installation is messed up now.

Comment: Yeahhh. :( Windows is messing everything up! I've decided to just dual boot linux. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try running command prompt as administrator,
or sudo since you seem to be on unix,
you install a package globally by using npm -g,

Comment: Thank you! I tried to install gulp globally as the administrator on command prompt and set the NPM folder to the node_modules there. When I used the npm root command in my projects directory, gulp still appeared to be installed in my local directory. Would that not be the cause of the issue?

Comment: not sure, I have limited experience with node, [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) may help, sorry i cannot be more help